# formulario para reserva de fechas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¿Como puedo hacer para comparar las fechas que tengo ya en `MySQL` con las que acabo de ingresar para saber si están disponibles?

Tengo un programa para reservar las fechas con horario de dos rampas que se tienen en la empresa, pero al momento de querer obtener los datos que ya están en `MySQL` para que los compare con los nuevos, al parecer no lo hace por que me sigue apareciendo el mensaje de `"FECHA Y HORA RESERVADA CORRECTAMENTE"`, aunque esté dentro del rango de fechas ya reservadas.

Les comparto el código:

```
<?php

include('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['save_solicitud'])) {

  $sql = "SELECT fechahoradel, fechahorahasta FROM solicitud";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  $del = $fechahoradel;
  $hasta = $fechahorahasta;
  $dbdel = $row['fechahoradel'];
  $dbhasta = $row['fechahorahasta'];

  if (($del >= $dbdel && $hasta <= $dbhasta) || ($del <= $dbdel && $hasta >= $dbhasta)) { 



  } else {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $area = $_POST['area'];
    $rampa = $_POST['rampa'];
    $fechahoradel = $_POST['fechahoradel'];
    $fechahorahasta = $_POST['fechahorahasta'];
    $comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO solicitud (nombre, area, rampa, fechahoradel, fechahorahasta, comentarios) VALUES ('$nombre', '$area', '$rampa', '$fechahoradel', '$fechahorahasta', '$comentarios')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Query Failed.");
    }
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'FECHA Y HORA RECERVADA CORRECTAMENTE';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';

  header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida. No entiendo bien tu duda. ¿Te refieres a que la inserción se hace aunque esa fecha ya existe? Si es así, ¿acaso pusiste una restricción de not duplicate en la tabla con respecto a las fechas? Y, si es así, ¿por qué no verificas si la fecha no existe antes de insertarla? Y, si no es eso, entonces explícate mejor, porque no se entiende. Gracias.

Comment: Quiero saber como comparar fechas que ya tengo en la base de datos con las que apenas voy a ingresar...no se en que parte del codigo tengo que extraer las fechas de la db, y como hacerlo para comparar...

Comment: Para comparar no tienes que extraer las fechas, sino recoger la fecha que fue dada y hacer una consulta para saber si esa fecha existe, algo así: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM laTabla WHERE laColumnaFecha=laFechaDada`, luego verificas si `total > 1`, lo cual indicará que existen registros con esa fecha o no.

Comment: Eso estaria bien, pero yo tengo que comparar dos fechas (una de inicio y una de cuando terminara) y quiero saber como compararlas para que no me deje insertar registros y las nuevas fechas se atraviesan con algunas que ya esten en la base de datos, no se si me de a entender con este if que tengo:

if (($del >= $dbdel && $hasta <= $dbhasta) || ($del <= $dbdel && $hasta >= $dbhasta)) {

Comment: Si son dos fechas no hay problema, harías la consulta en base a dos fechas, algo así: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM laTabla WHERE laColumnaFechaUno=laFechaUnoDada AND laColumnaFechaDos=laFechaDosDada`

Comment: Supongamos que tengo una fecha reservada en mi db para un salon para el dia desde 29/09/2019 17:00:00 hasta el 29/09/2019 22:00:00, y llega una persona a quererme reservar ese salon del 29/09/2019 15:00:00 hasta el 29/09/2019 23:00:00, como hago para saber que yo ya tengo una fecha reservada ese dia ?

Comment: Antes de responder a esa pregunta habría que saber cómo tienes diseñada la tabla que registra esa información, qué columnas tiene, cómo has pensado la organización de las tablas, la relación entre ellas, las columnas que guardan la fecha de inicio y de fin, etc. Por eso te decía que no haces nada con resolverlo por programación si en la base de datos el modelo de datos está mal concebido.

Comment: Solo tengo una tabla llamada "solicitud" donde ingreso los siguientes datos: nombre, area, rampa, fechahoradel, fechahorahasta, comentarios